# Trying to find whether my PHP variable has any content

Tags: php, isset

Hi I have a PHP variable called Keyword, what I am trying to find out is if there is any content in the variable.

```
 if (isset($keyword)) {
```

Using the above code it returns values that are blank.

Comment: Try just: `if ($keyword) {...}`. That should fail if `$keyword == ''`

Comment: If you phrased your question more clearly, you might get answers for detecting non-space variable content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
trim($keyword);
if (isset($keyword) && !empty($keyword)) {
    // Code here
}
```

Edit:

This fixed your problem because you had trailing whitespace in your variable. even though it appeared empty it still had a space or carriage return.

Answer (score 3):

Use [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

```
if (isset($keyword) && !empty($keyword)) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
if (!empty($keyword)) {
```